# React JS Highcharts Zoom in and x and y axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I want to zoom a graph in x and y axis but separately not using zoomType : 'xy'. Can Someone explain me how can I switch between zooming in on x and y axis

Comment: I am not sure how particular zoom should be triggered... Could you explain how it should work?

Comment: If I am holding ctrl key then zoom option should be changed to Y axis and without holding the ctrl key it should just zoom in y direction

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible to implement from the API options and requires custom code. Have you considered using a simple button to switch between the chart zoom types? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4syea93g/